# Three way modeling django

Tags: django, data-modeling

I want to model a schema for an award function in django. I have a User model, a show model and an award model. A user can get one award for a show. I can simply say User 'aaa' gets award 'bbb'. but then that award cannot be associated with other user for another show.

I think there is three way modeling required for User, show and Award. Is there any sophisticated way of doing it? I know about 'through' but dont think this can be a good tool here. If it is could you please guide me how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an extra model, I will call it `UserAward`.

```
class UserAward(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    award = models.ForeignKey(Award)
    show = models.ForeignKey(Show)
```

Comment: would this allow me adding multiple records for same show id? or record id?

Comment: You would create an instance of this model every time a user was given an award.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems reasonable to me. I think I was over thinking with Through relationship

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't add any constraints as I don't know the specifics, but perhaps you might want to say that award and show are unique together, to prevent the same award being given twice at the same show.

Comment: Actually It turned out I cannot have two unique constraint at the same time.

Comment: ```class Meta:
 unique_together = ('show', 'award')
 unique_together = ('show', 'winner')```                               When I try to do this only later one stays.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When I try to enforce two unique constraints only later one stays.

Comment: The second value is over-writing the first. I think you need to do `unique_together = ( ('show', 'award'), ('show', 'winner') )`